# Tiempo de ejecucion de mi script en php solo dura 30 segundos

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente problema cuando ejecuto mi script en php solo dura 30 segundos cortando la misma que no es un exceso de proceso, lo que pasa es que estoy importando informacion ya probe cambiando en el `ini` :

```
max_execution_time=300
max_input_time=600
memory_limit=256M
```

tambien en linea de comando

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); 
set_time_limit(300);
```

Lo peor es que revisando la configuracion de `php.ini` la directiva si me la muestra con el cambio, el `safe_mode` esta en `off`.

No se me ocurre que mas hacer.

Gracias

Comment: si tu pregunta es sobre php, que tiene que ver la etiqueta java?

Comment: Reiniciaste los servicios _Apache y MySQL_ después de realizar el cambio en `.ini`?

Comment: Si reinicie Apache, uso SQL Server

Comment: podiras agregar que estas ejecutando dentro de tu codigo... para tener una idea.. y poder ayudarte